# How to use opencv to spilt a multi-object mask to masks which is with only one object

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want use opencv to spilt an oringal mask with two objects like [mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI9Rf.jpg) into two masks which has only one object like [spilt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SVbd.jpg) [spilt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgfqj.jpg)
Is there a good way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: if objects dont overlap you can use findContours and drawContours to separate the mask.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post any code that you have written to try and solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have solved the problem using cv2.findContours.